# if statement to match users input to string answer

Tags: java, android

I'm doing a word shuffle app on android studio for a class project. I need help understanding how I can get the users input and match it to the correct String answer. I tried a few approaches and have fallen short. I tried using an `if(word.equals(userAnswer))` statement but having a hard time understanding it. How can I write the if statement for text input/output to match my answer in android studio?

(Optional question) Also is  public void OnClick(View v) a good approach or should I go with something else?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    private EditText userAnswer;
    private TextView answerOutput;
    private TextView scrambledWord;

    public void OnClick(View v){
        scrambledWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrambledWord);
        userAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerInput);
        answerOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerOutput);           
        Button button = (Button) v;

        String word = "Animals"; // scan for word

        ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(word.length()); // gets array with length of word
        for ( char c : word.toCharArray() ) {
            chars.add(c);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(chars); //shuffles the characters
        char[] shuffled = new char[chars.size()];
        for ( int i = 0; i < shuffled.length; i++ ) {
            shuffled[i] = chars.get(i);
        }
        String shuffledWord = new String(shuffled);

        if (word.equals(userAnswer)){
            answerOutput.setText("Correct!!");
        } else {
            answerOutput.setText("Sorry try again.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will allow you to determine if they are the same

```
if(word.equalsIgnoreCase(userAnswer.getText().toString())) {
    answerOutput.setText("Correct");
}
```

However, generally speaking you have a much larger problem, unless it's in code somewhere that you aren't showing us.

Somewhere in your activity onCreate/onStart you want to initialize your button with whatever view it might be.

```
Button checkAnswer = (Button) findViewById(//whatever your id is)
```

Then you want to set the onClick listener of the button. With the approach that you are using, it would end up needing two things. First this

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
```

Then in you need to set the onClick listener to your Button, probably in OnCreate.

```
checkAnswer.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Then your onClick would look something like

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (word.equals(userAnswer)){

        answerOutput.setText("Correct!!");

    }

    else {

        answerOutput.setText("Sorry try again.");
    }

}
```

The logic for scrambling the word etc, probably wouldn't be in onClick here.

Also, if you have multiple things you want to set click listeners for you would do something like this

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     switch(v.getId()) {
         case(R.id.//whatever): {
               //dosomething
              break;
          }
     }
 }
```

Where you can multiple cases for all of the views that you have set the MainActivity to handle.

Edit: Since you updated your code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

private EditText userAnswer;
private TextView answerOutput;
private TextView scrambledWord;
private String word;
private String shuffledWord;
private Button button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    scrambledWord = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.scrambledWord);
    userAnswer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.answerInput);
    answerOutput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answerOutput); 
    createWord();
    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private void createWord() {
    word = "Animals";
    ArrayList<Character> chars = new ArrayList<Character>(word.length()); // gets array with length of word
    for ( char c : word.toCharArray() ) {
        chars.add(c);
    }
    Collections.shuffle(chars); //shuffles the characters
    char[] shuffled = new char[chars.size()];
    for ( int i = 0; i < shuffled.length; i++ ) {
        shuffled[i] = chars.get(i);
    }
    shuffledWord = new String(shuffled);
    shuffledText.setText(shuffledWord);
}

@Override
public void OnClick(View v){
    if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(userAnswer.getText().toString())){
        answerOutput.setText("Correct!!");
    } else {
        answerOutput.setText("Sorry try again.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks warlock trying this right now.

Comment: Thank you for your wonderful help. It was very intuitive, allowed me to understand things better. I have 1 question, I'm getting a error with the following shuffledText.setText (cannot resolve symbol) - I set a private shuffledText but the problem still remains, and if (word.equalsIgnoreCase(userAnswer.getText())) is giving me a "in String cannot be applied to android.text.Editable"

Comment: I just noticed this too. I'm getting a class "Main activity" must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method OnClickview in OnClickListener for the public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {  What does that mean?

Comment: I resolved the first error with the userAnswer.getText. Working on the others as we speak. thanks.

Comment: Never mind, errors are resolved. Figured it out. Thanks for your help! :)

Comment: Sorry! I left work, and meant to check back in again because I didn't have a chance to put this in AS to make sure there weren't any errors, however, glad to have been of help

Comment: No problem. You did more than enough to help and I appreciate every bit of it. I'll vote you up but people keep lowering my reputation for some reason lol. Once i'm able to vote you up I will. Promise.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the onClickListener of the button to your MainActivity?

Your MainActivity should implement OnClickListener too

Comment: Good call on that. I didn't realize the importance of it and considered using it but didn't. I'll give it a shot. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to but it says I need 15 rep points lol. I will as soon as i'm able to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `userAnswer.getText()` to get the answer. Your `userAnswer` variable currently is of type `EditText`, which means a check to see if `word.equals(userAnswer)` will always return false, as they are of different types. Instead, try `word.equals(userAnswer.getText())` to check if their answer equals **the original word**. To check if their answer equals the scrambled word, use `shuffledWord.equals(userAnswer.getText())`.

Comment: Awesome! Great info, much appreciated. Will try this now. I'm starting to get a hang of the getText and setText's. Just didn't know when and where to use them. Thanks again!